# Returning a list of values in SQL, get conversion error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, list

I'm trying to return a list of fields from a column in a string in SQL. I think I found a way to tackle the problem, but I keep getting a conversion error... It's this that has me stuck, I don't think I'm doing a conversion, and I don't want to anyway. Here's the code:

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' , '') + my_column --It's datatype is int.
FROM my_table
WHERE my_id_column = @id
SELECT @listStr
```

Comment: Try using `+ CONVERT(varchar(10),my_column)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use convert function with date format that you want.

[SQL DateTime Format Function](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' , '') + convert(varchar(10),my_column)
FROM my_table
WHERE my_id_column = @id
SELECT @listStr
```

Comment: It is an int. I want a list of numbers as output. But I figured it's the same concept. Converting to a normal varchar works. Though, I'm still mystified, I'm not sure why I have to convert...?

Comment: You have to use convert function as that column datatype is INT and you are trying to concatenate that INT column to varhcar variable.

Comment: Ok... What had me confused was the error output was that it failed to convert to int... And returned the first part of the list already.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to convert the int value from "my_column" to text data type to enable SQL Server concatenate the value along with the @listStr value.

This example ilustrates the a correct code to your purpose:

```
DECLARE @Text TABLE
( 
    LineId int
    , LineText nvarchar(70)
)

DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT INTO @Text VALUES ( 1, 'This')
INSERT INTO @Text VALUES ( 1, 'is')
INSERT INTO @Text VALUES ( 1, 'a')
INSERT INTO @Text VALUES ( 1, 'text')

SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + ', ' , '') + ltrim(rtrim(convert(varchar(20),LineText)))
FROM @Text
WHERE LineId = 1

SELECT @listStr
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

JUST replace your query

```
 declare @pt nvarchar(max)
 SET @pt = STUFF(
 (


 select CAST(',' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + cast([tagCloudID] as nvarchar)  
 from (
 SELECT         tagCloudFeatureContentID.tagCloudID 
 FROM            tagCloudFeatureContentID  

   )  A
 FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, '')


 select @pt
```